# request.POST.get('username') returns NONE

Tags: django

```
def profile(request): 
    Exist_Emails = User.objects.filter(is_active=True).values_list('email', flat=True)
    Exist_Usernames = User.objects.filter(is_active=True).values_list('username', flat=True)
    current_user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    Email_Invalid = False
    Username_Invalid = False
    if request.method != 'POST':


        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    else:
        update_username = request.POST.get('username')
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                               request.FILES,
                               instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()
            update_u_form = u_form.save(commit=False)

#Problem occurs in this if statement!
          if update_u_form.username in Exist_Usernames and update_u_form.username != current_user.username:
                Username_Invalid = True
                u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=current_user) ##
                messages.error(request, 'The username already eixts')

#But it worked in this elif statement which is almost the same!

            elif update_u_form.email in Exist_Emails and update_u_form.email != current_user.email:
                Email_Invalid = True
                u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=current_user)
                messages.error(request, 'The email already exits.')

            else:
                update_u_form.save()
                return redirect('/users/profile/')


    context = {
    'u_form': u_form, 'p_form': p_form,'update_username': 
    update_username,'Email_Invalid': Email_Invalid,'current_user': 
    current_user, 'Username_Invalid': Username_Invalid}
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

This is the html template:

```
{% if Email_Invalid == "True" or Username_Invalid == "True" %}

{{ current_user.username }}
</div>
<div style="font-size:16px;">
{{ current_user.email }}
</div>

<p>"Sorry, the email or username already exits."</p>

{% else %}

{{ user.username }}
</div>
<div style="font-size:16px;">
{{ user.email }}
</div>
{% endif %}

{{Username_Invalid}}
{{update_username}}





<form method="post" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ u_form.as_p }}
    {{ p_form.as_p }}
   <button name="sumbit" class="btn btn-primary" >Update</button>
</form>
```

My forms.py:

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']
```

As I type in updated username, and press submit. However The `{{Username_Invalid}}` returns `False` which is supposed to be True in if statement.

Then I checked `{{update_username}}` which returns `NONE`!! update_username here is just request.POST.get('username').

What is going on? I thought `UserUpdateForm` should inherit from User model. So `request.POST` should have a dictionary key-value pair `'username':username`.

My debugging process:

What I am trying to do is to display `(instance = current_user)` in u_form when the user tries to edit email or username but these email or username  has already been registered in database by others.

It works perfectly fine in the email field, but when I edit username to be sth that has already been registered by another user, the instance however displays whatever I typed in(It should print `instance = current_user` not request.user).

So I found out that when I did this , it didn't enter the first IF statement after `is_valid`, as  `Username_Invalid` still prints `False`. Then I checked if something is wrong with '`update_u_form.username`' , so I set

```
update_username = request.POST.get('username')
```

to print out the value, and it returns `NONE`. I think this is where the problem is but can't figure out why.

Comment: post your full view, I think you forgot to render `update_username` with your context

Comment: K I thought my views is bit too long so I skipped it here

Comment: but need to see what your are actually rendering

Comment: Try `request.POST.data['username']`

Comment: The user is in the request.user object

To get the username it would be request.user.username 

You would have to access the usermodel finding the user based upon that, after that you can change your username which is what I guess you are doing?

Let me know if any of that helps.

Comment: @JodyFitzpatrick. Sorry I am a newbie. I don't quite understand what you mean. I tried update_user=request.POST.get('user') and it returns NONE either. Did you mean request.POST.get('username') will not return username because it should theoretically be something like .get('user.username')?

Comment: You are trying to fetch POST data from an if block with condition != POST.

Comment: @art06 I set current_user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username) before the if block. So the first time I request to enter the page, it should have already been fetched and stored to the variable 'current_user' right? Then I put    !=current_user.username. Then current_user.username should not =POST I guess? please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you

Comment: What does the ProfileUpdateForm do? What fields does it have?

Comment: Can you try the same thing but with a single form on the page?